# A Mercurial-from-git guide

Tags: git, github, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm feeling there are some serious differences between Mercurial and git philosophy. This causes me to make mistakes often.

I'm looking for an everyday cheat sheet which explains:

- what is identical, just has different commands
- what differs and can cause problems

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are startlingly few differences between Mercurial and git anymore.  Mostly just differences in terminology around branching (what git calls a 'branch' Mercurial calls a "bookmark", and what Mercurial calls a "branch" has no analog in git).  This page covers that pretty well: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts?highlight=%28gitconcepts%29

Also there's a great compare/contrast on branching in Mercurial and git at: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/ which is written with git users as the primary audience

The bottom of that first link does have a table that shows how git's commands map to Mercurial's, but it's best to understand how conceptually and functionally similar they are rather than committing the conversions to memory.

Comment: My opinion is this differences can cause dramatic misunderstanding if you don't know about them!

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying they're neither "philosophical" nor "functional", just "terminology"